# Visual Studio 2010 crashes when starting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash

Visual Studio 2010 crashes when loading

Just trying to start Visual Studio 2010 to an empty environment, no project, solution, or file, but it crashes. It was working fine a few days ago.

I've tried reinstalling VS SP1 with the Repair option. I've tried the `/SafeMode` and `/ResetSettings` switches. I also tried runnign with the `/Log` switch but I don't see anything about an error in the log file.

My setup: VS 2010 Professional edition, SP1 running on Windows XP.

Comment: Check this link: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/567979/visual-studio-2010-crashes-on-startup ,  found on this blog: http://dipdapdop.com/2010/10/13/visual-studio-2010-wpf-font-cache/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by stopping the WPFFontCache process and deleting the ".dat" files from "C:\Documents and Settings\LocalService\Local Settings\Application Data" and then restarting.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2010/03/02/visual-studio-2010-crash-on-startup.aspx